# Can't get ValueInjecter to map COM objects

Tags: c#, automapper, valueinjecter

See the following code. The test passed when using AutoMapper, but failed when using ValueInjecter:

```
using NetFwTypeLib;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        INetFwPolicy2 policy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(
                Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
        INetFwRules fwRules = policy.Rules;
        Rule rule = new Rule();

        foreach (INetFwRule fwRule in fwRules)
        {
            if (fwRule.Name == "HomeGroup Out")
            {
                //AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<INetFwRule, Rule>();
                //AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(fwRule, rule);
                rule.InjectFrom(fwRule);
                break;
            }
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(rule.Name == "HomeGroup Out");
    }
}

public class Rule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Based on Omu's answer, it seems the problem is related to COM objects, not only FirewallAPI.dll classes. So I changed title from "*Can't get ValueInjecter to map FirewallAPI.dll classes*" to "*Can't get ValueInjecter to map COM objects*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't work because doing:

```
fwRule.GetType().GetProperties().Count()// is 0
```

or doing the same using `PropertyDescriptor` also return zero, it's like the object doesn't has properties

the solution is to write an injection that will take the type from where to get the properties:

```
public class Same<T> : ValueInjection
{
   protected override void Inject(object source, object target)
   {
       var props = typeof (T).GetInfos().ToArray();
       var tp = target.GetInfos().ToArray();
       for (var i = 0; i < props.Count(); i++)
       {
          var prop = props[i];
          for (var j = 0; j < tp.Count(); j++)
          {
            if(prop.Name == tp[j].Name && prop.PropertyType == tp[j].PropertyType)
            tp[j].SetValue(target,prop.GetValue(source, null),null);
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

and the usage:

```
rule.InjectFrom<Same<INetFwRule>>(fwRule);
```

this is the same as the default InjectFrom() but it reads the target properties from the supplied Type

Comment: So it seems the problem is ValueInjector can't get the real type of `fwRule`. `fwRule` is a COM object. Using `GetType()` returns `System.__ComObject`. AutoMapper works fine with COM objects because I can tell it the real type through `Mapper.CreateMap<INetFwRule, Rule>()`. Any workaround for ValueInjector? Thanks.